# WCF error: "The service cannot cache the negotiation state as the capacity '128' has been reached"

Tags: wcf, caching

I'm trying to find out why one of my WCF services sometimes randomly makes the lsass process take 100% of the CPU. I was looking through the WCF trace logs and found this error many times:

```
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededException: The service cannot cache the negotiation state as the capacity '128' has been reached. Retry the request.</ExceptionString>
```

The WCF service is hosted in IIS6.
I've searched online but can't find what this actually means, or where I can set the capacity, or what might be causing the cache to get full.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever find a solution for this problem? Because I also have this problem but on an IIS7.5 and IIS8.5